# Update/Set value with change from one month to the next in a Pandas dataframe(s)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have monthly data that has customer product and service information. A customer can make changes to their account and add service or cancel a service, etc. I need to be able to capture these changes from one month to the next. So I have some sample data that looks like:

```
Month       AcctKey     AcctNo              PrdDs       PrdCd   Units
7/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    TPLBBVCEVID FTV     1
7/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    TPLBBVCEVID FDR     1
7/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    TPLBBVCEVID RAL     2
8/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    DBLVCEVID   FDR     0
8/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    DBLVCEVID   VPR     1
8/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    DBLVCEVID   RAL     1
8/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    DBLVCEVID   FTV     1
8/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    DBLVCEVID   FIR     2
9/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    DBLVCEVID   RAL     0
9/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    DBLVCEVID   FTV     1
9/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    DBLVCEVID   VPR     1
9/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    DBLVCEVID   FIR     2
```

This was three dataframes that I concatenated. It's an example of a single customers records for 3 months in 2016. This "customer" cancelled a service and added some others. This can be seem more clearly pivoted:

```
Month       AcctKey     AcctNo              PrdDs       FDR FIR FTV RAL VPR
7/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    TPLBBVCEVID 1   0   1   2   0
8/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    DBLVCEVID   0   2   1   1   1
9/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    DBLVCEVID   0   2   1   0   1
```

In Aug FDR was cancelled, FIR was added, FTV had no change, RAL downgraded and eventually cancelled in Sep, and VPR was added.

I'm looking to create another dataframe like:

```
Month       AcctKey     AcctNo              PrdDs         FDR   FIR FTV RAL VPR     PrdDsMvmt       FDRMvmt       FIRMvmt         FTVMvmt         RALMvmt       VPRMvmt
7/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    TPLBBVCEVID   1     0     1   2   0     -               -               -               -               -             -
8/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    DBLVCEVID     0     2     1   1   1     DBLVCEVID       out           in              no_change       down          in
9/1/2016    14162010    100ZZ01010109999    DBLVCEVID     0     2     1   0   1     no_change       no_change     no_change       no_change       out           no_change
```

The dashes in the first month for July indicate to me this is the first record. Note that the actual dataset can be up to 2 million rows (possibly more) for a single month.

Comment: I can't see any difference in your last two dataframes.  Also don't see the "dashes" you are referring to.  But regardless, are you just looking for `diff()`?

Comment: There are six new columns in the last dataframe and the dashes are in the first row of these new columns. From July to Aug FDR decreased to 0 which indicates it was cancelled. Column FDRMvmt should show this as an "out". FIR went from 0 to 2 so column FIRMvmt should show this as "in" which measn it's a new service for this customer. Each month when I pull in the new data I would like to compare to the previous month and update the *Mvmt columns according to their PrdCd columns. Changes in FDR would cause an update to FDRMvmt. Tracking product movement for each customer month-to-month.

Comment: oh, I see, had to scroll to the right.  this is really just a matter of hand coding using the row value plus previous row value.  Something like `df['new'] = np.where( df.event < df.shift().event, 'drop', df.event )`

Comment: Thanks @JohnE. I see how this can work. I need to be able to compare for <, >, ==. So do you know how to do an OR with shift? Something like df_pivot['FDRMvmt'] = np.where((df_pivot.FDR < df_pivot.shift().FDR, 'drop', '') | (df_pivot.FDR > df_pivot.shift().FDR, 'add', '') | (df_pivot.FDR == df_pivot.shift().FDR, 'no_change', '')). I get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'tuple' and 'tuple' with this.

Comment: Well, I would just pivot once and save that to work with.  After that, just do stuff like `(condition1) | (condition2)` and the parentheses are necessary not optional in this case